# Python function optional and required parameters clarification

Tags: python

I’m trying to understand python function parameter rules.

If the python range function is:

```
range(start=None, stop, step=None)
```

How does it accept a required argument in place after an optional argument? I thought the rule was that required arguments had to come first in the definition unless keywords are used for all of them, or everything after the required parameters.

Comment: Where do you see that signature? The official ones in the docs are `class range(stop)` and `class range(start, stop[, step])`.

Comment: That isn't signature a valid signature for `range`. See the signatures given in the [builtins docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: It was in several answers to previous questions here. I tried to find the actual signature for the definition online, including Python docs, but couldn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between defining a new function and calling a function, so in the first case when creating a new function, you need to create the header of your function in this way (not_necessary has a default value here) :

```py
def new_function(necessary, not_necessary=None):
     # Some logic here...

# Calling the function
necessary = True
new_function(necessary)
```

When calling this function you can switch the variable(props) but you need to specify each variable name(specifying only one does not satisfy the rule):

```py
new_function(not_necessary=False, necessary=True)
```

Without calling by name you should respect the order given by the definition.

Comment: I’ve realized that I can be clearer, I am wondering is how a required parameter is after an optional one. How do you write that definition?

Comment: This case can be achieved in one way : new_function(not_necessary=False, necessary=True)

You need to declare the name of your variable in the header in this way! if you don't python compiler will set the variables by default in the declaration order.